# Rails 3 I18n routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have such routes in my app:

```
# config/routes.rb
Demo::Application.routes.draw do  
  root :to => "requests#index"
  match 'find' => 'requests#find'
  get "about/developer"
  get "about/api"
end
```

All works ok.
But I want to enable I18n urls and changed routes: **(by the [official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)):**

```
# config/routes.rb
Demo::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)"  do
    root :to => "requests#index"
    get "about/developer"
    get "about/api"
    match 'find' => 'requests#find'
  end
end
```

After adding `scope` lines it gives error:

> Exiting
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:160:in
>   `default_controller_and_action':
>   missing :controller (ArgumentError)

What's up? Official guide is wrong?

My Rails version: 3.0.3, Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work if you specify all of the controller/action names?

In other words, try changing:

```
get "about/developer"
get "about/api"
```

to:

```
get "about/developer" => "about#developer"
get "about/api" => "about#api"
```

Comment: Why would adding a scope make a get request not route as usual?

Comment: outside the `scope` block, the `get` function delegates the routing to a `match` function which in turn calls other helper functions based on the  construction of this `get` statement. This `match` call then calls another `_match` (or `match!`) method which does the actual routing (or something of the like). I think with the `scope` method, the `match` performed bypasses the fancy pre-`match` method. _Names of the method may not be accurate but the process is._